# What is the equivalent of shell variables $@ in windows command?

Tags: batch, command-line-arguments

I want to put a variable in my command batch script for multiple arguments as the number may vary. Just as in shell we use $@. I tried several things but nothing is working.

[Edit : I know %* works, but actually needed to use the SHIFT operator to remove the first argument and assign the rest to a variable. But when I do SHIFT and check %*, it still shows all the original argument unlike in unix shell.]

At present I am using a FOR loop to do that, but wanted to know if there is any other command/method to POP the first argument and assign the rest to another variable.

eg : SomeCommand "multiple arguments"

Comment: Thanks @harrymc for the prompt reply. Sorry I put the wrong query and have edited it. Please do let me know if you have some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

`%*` in a batch file holds all of the arguments passed to the script
(excluding the script name itself)
exactly as they were written.

You might also find these useful:

`%0` - the command used to call the batch file (could be `foo`, `..\foo`, `c:\bats\foo.bat`, etc.)
`%1` is the first command line parameter,
`%2` is the second command line parameter,
and so on till `%9` (and
[SHIFT](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html)
can be used for those after the 9th).

See
[How-to: Pass Command Line arguments (Parameters) to a Windows batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

An example for using `SHIFT` for the following command:

```
batchfile.bat The Quick Brown
```

- As given: `%0`=The Quick Brown, `%1`=The, `%2`=Quick, `%3`=Brown.
- After SHIFT: `%0`=The Quick Brown, `%1`=Quick, `%2`=Brown
- After a second SHIFT: `%0`=The Quick Brown, `%1`=Brown

For the question of "everything but the first parameter" there is no good
answer. The batch language is not precise enough for a method that works
for all possible parameters, so using SHIFT is the best method.

A discussion of possible solutions can be found in the post
[Is there a way to indicate the last n parameters in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761615/is-there-a-way-to-indicate-the-last-n-parameters-in-a-batch-file)